# Issue about Cloth Simulation

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I have followed several tutorials on the Youtube.

This is the cloth I made, I double check there is no duplicated vertex left in the mesh.

[image]

I also applied the scale and rotation for both cloth and human body.

[image]
[image]

This is the result occurred in the last period.

[image]

I have tried to add subdivisions and still get a wired result

[image]

I have no idea about how to fix this issue.

Comment: pls upload blend file. There are a lot of reasons possible for this

Comment: Here is the link to download this blender file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t-RIXcjIPi4ujR8g3hxExlUOrZnInZfN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The back of the cloth template has flipped normals. Select the back part of the mesh and flip it with Alt+N in *Edit* mode. Also, don't apply the *Subdivision* modifier. You have added edges before you added the modifier and there are now edges missing and the existing edges are subdivided. This will create holes at the seams.

Comment: I have tried doing the flip normals, the back of cloth works. Thanks, the rest issue as you mentioned about the edges, I will try to redo the edges according the tutorial again! Thank you!

Comment: What does it look like in the tutorial? Blender has a bug (or feature, I don't know) It does not remove the threads nor does it merge the vertices of the islands. If you want to see the seams with a *Solidify* modifier you need to clean up the mesh a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a test with the following changes:

- turned off *Self-Collision* as suggested by *BlenderMaster15*
- lowered *Collision > Distance* to `5 mm` to get the fabric is closer to the body
- lowered the *Collision > Softbody & Cloth > Thickness Outer* value to `0.001` also to get the fabric is closer to the body
- use *Elastic Deformation* brush in *Sculpt* mode and made the upper parts of the sleeves a bit wider. Rotate the end of the sleeves a bit (*Pose* brush) and straightened the back of the neck.
- flipped the faces of the back
- added more threads

[image: sewing prepare]

The result after 30 frames:

[image: sewing result]

There are still some glitches and the mesh islands are not connected. But this can be changed manually (or with a script) after the *Cloth* modifier has been applied.

Comment: Thank you for your test!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Turn off "Self-Collisons" in the shirt's cloth modifier.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have turned off the "Self-Collisons" trigger and it seems that the cloth is not weird like before, But still cannot seems like the same as the effect of tutorial.